# Why is only the first shadow that I render at the correct position?

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

I am working on a Java + LWJGL Project. Currently I am trying to implement Variance Shadow Mapping, but only the first shadow map that I sample in my shader shows up at the correct position.

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 passTexCoords;
in vec4[4] shadowCoords;

//Fragment color
out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D modelTexture;
uniform sampler2D[4] shadowMaps;

#define SHADOW_BIAS 0.0005

float linstep(float low, float high, float v) {
    return clamp((v-low)/(high-low), 0.0, 1.0);
}

//compare ... The depth of the fragment in shadow map sapce
float sampleVarianceShadowMap(in sampler2D shadowMap, in vec2 coords, in float compare) {

    /* This is the Code that I want to use when I know what the problem was.
    vec2 moments = texture(shadowMap, coords.xy).rg;

    float p = step(compare, moments.x);
    float variance = max(moments.y - moments.x * moments.x, 0.00002);

    float d = compare - moments.x;
    float pMax = linstep(0.2, 1.0, variance / (variance + d*d));

    return min(max(p, pMax), 1.0);
    */

    //============================================================================HERE=========================================================================HERE====================
    //THE ERROR OCCURES HERE:

    //This doesn't work:
    float visibility = step(compare-SHADOW_BIAS, texture(shadowMap, coords.xy).r);  
    return visibility;

    //The shadows on the ground move in a weird way when the camera moves.

    //But this does:
    return step(compare-SHADOW_BIAS, texture(shadowMap, coords.xy).r);

    //With this code the shadows are at the correct place.

    //===========================================================================HERE==========================================================================HERE=====================
}

//To create a smooth darkness falloff at the edge of the shadow map
float calcShadowMapVisibilityFalloff(in vec2 coords, in float falloffStart, in float gradient) {
    float distFromTexCenter = length(coords * vec2(2.0) - vec2(1.0));
    float falloff = (clamp(pow(distFromTexCenter, gradient), falloffStart, 1.0) - falloffStart) * (1/(1-falloffStart));

    if(falloff > 1.0 || falloff < 0.0) {
        falloff = 0;
    }

    return 1-falloff;
}

void main(void){

    float shadowInvertedBrightness = 1.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < shadowMaps.length(); i++)
    {
        float visibility = 1 - sampleVarianceShadowMap(shadowMaps[i], shadowCoords[i].xy, shadowCoords[i].z);
        shadowInvertedBrightness -= (visibility / shadowMaps.length()) * calcShadowMapVisibilityFalloff(shadowCoords[i].xy, 0.85, 2.0);
    }

    shadowInvertedBrightness = clamp(shadowInvertedBrightness, 0.2, 1.0);

    //.bgra because I save textures with the BGRA format (I've read its faster)
    out_Color = texture(modelTexture, passTexCoords).bgra * vec4(shadowInvertedBrightness,shadowInvertedBrightness,shadowInvertedBrightness,1);
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

//Vertex coords
in vec3 position;
//Texture coords
in vec2 texCoords;

//The MVP matrix of the entity
uniform mat4 MVPMat;
//The "To Shadow Map Space" matrix
uniform mat4[4] shadowMVPBiasMats;
//The Transformation matrix of the entity
uniform mat4 transformMat;

out vec2 passTexCoords;
//Shadow map sample coords
out vec4[4] shadowCoords;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = MVPMat * vec4(position, 1.0);

    vec4 worldPos = transformMat * vec4(position, 1.0);

    for(int i = 0; i < shadowMVPBiasMats.length(); i++) {
        shadowCoords[i] = shadowMVPBiasMats[i] * worldPos;
    }

    passTexCoords = texCoords;
}
```

Full Code (Example Project that you can import in Eclipse) and Screenshots:

- [Screenshots and source code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0ObvqVdqoTURTNlSTc4LWdLOEE) (Shader files at src/ShadowTest/rendering/, Screenshots at Screenshots/)

System Information:

- OS: Windows Home, Version: 10.0.15063
- GPU: Intel HD Graphics 520
- GPU Driver Version: 20.19.15.4642 (By Medion)

Comment: Please supply more info.Some screen shots etc. You see people downvoted you.That's because there is no way to help with the data you supplied.Also, GLSL is not enough. You problem can be on the client side with the shader inputs.

Comment: I would recommend to test your shadowMap one by one, first remove your main and just add float visibility = 1; if(shadowCoord[i].z-SHADOW_BIAS > texture(shadowMap[i], shadowCoord[i].xy).r) { visibility = 0; } out_Color = texture(modelTexture, passTexCoords).bgra * vec4(visibility,visibility,visibility,1); and tell us one you see. You can also try to save your shadow map on the disk and display them in a viewer

Comment: If you need more code or screenshots, please have a look at the Google Drive link. Also I will try what Draykoon D said.

Comment: I've tried what Draykoon D said and hard-coded the index, which shadow map is used in the array. Both shadows are displayed correctly. But if I test them individually and use my sample function, only the shadow map with index 0 (the first) will work. If I change the order in which I load the shadow maps, still only the one with index 0 works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an bug in the driver, because it doesn't happen when I run the program with my NVIDIA GPU.

A Workaround for the problem:

```
float textureShadowMap(in sampler2D shadowMap, in vec2 coords) {
    return texture(shadowMap, coords).r;
}
```

And in the sampleVarianceShadowMap Method:

```
float visibility = step(compare-SHADOW_BIAS, textureShadowMap(shadowMap, coords));  
return visibility;
```

Since I am not 100% sure that it is a bug, it would be nice if someone can confirm this.